# Saving results of a for loop as a vector in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I'm running an experiment that involves people listening to a series of tones (either high or low pitched) and counting the high tones. I have a vector how many tones (in total) they actually heard:

```
count=c(1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2)
```

All participants heard subsets of the same series of tones, in this specific order:

```
list=c("high", "low", "low", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", 
       "high", "high", "low", "low", "high", "low", "low")
```

I want to know specifically how many high tones each participant actually heard. So, in this example, if they heard 3 tones in total, they only heard one high tone, but if they heard 5 tones in total they heard 2 high tones.

To do this, I tried making a for loop to count the number of occurrences of "high" for each participant:

```
for (i in count){
  cat(length(grep("high", list[1:i])))
}
```

This prints out all the correct numbers of high tones (in this case: 11211111121). However, I want to create and store this output as a vector of individual values.

My question is, how do I save the output of this for loop as a vector of values?

Answer (score 1):

This stores each value as one entry in a vector.

```
tones <- c("high", "low", "low", "low", "high", "low", "high", "low", 
       "high", "high", "low", "low", "high", "low", "low")

count <- c(1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 2)

x <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(count)){
x[i]  <-  length(grep("high", list[1:count[i]]))
}

> x
 [1] 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's usually best to avoid `for` loops in R.

```
> vapply(count, function(i) sum(list[1:i] == 'high'), integer(1))
[1] 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1
```